# Android black screen when app started

Tags: android

When I start my app at first time, it shows me the drawable at first, and then shows black screen before showing my splash activity layout for a split of a second when the activity's onCreate method is called. I've set theme for the splash activity.Here is my code:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Beast.MainActivity" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:name=".BeastBikes"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Beast"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Beast.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="speedx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <data android:scheme="speedx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

my MainActivity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreate is called!");
    hasBeenLaunched = true;
    this.sp = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), 0);

    new AdviertiseManager(MainActivity.this).adviertiseLoad();

    this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            intentToNext();
        }
    }, 3000L);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (null != handler) {
        handler = null;
    }
}

/**
 * 跳转到下个页面
 */
private void intentToNext() {
    if (!this.sp.getBoolean(TutorialActivity.PREF_HAS_SHOWN, false) && LocaleManager.isChineseTimeZone()) {
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this, TutorialActivity.class));
        this.finish();
    } else {
        this.gotoAuthenticationPageIfNeeded();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the full file of `Manifest.xml` ??

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] with the Java code?